# Terraform - Multiple maps with lists

Tags: terraform

I struggle to loop through my data structure. If anyone have any feedback regarding my data structure, this is highly desirable

**Data structure**

```
locals = {
  values = {
    key1 = ["a", "b"],
    key2 = ["c", "d"]
  }
}
```

**What I've tried**

```
value = { for key, value in local.values : key => values }
```

This basically prints out `local.array` as is. I know I should have the ability to loop through the `value` given in the expression above, but I'm not able to do so.

**Desired output**

```
# Following does NOT work
value = { for key, values in local.values : key => 
            for v in values : key => v}

Key1: a
Key1: b
Key2: c
Key2: d
```

Comment: A map cannot have the same key twice so it doesnt make sense what your trying to do here. are you trying to make a list of maps?

Answer (score 1):

A map must have unique keys, you cannot use the same key twice. you could vor example make a map of the values to keys like.

```
locals {
  values = {
    key1 = ["a", "b"],
    key2 = ["c", "d"]
  }
}

output "vals" {
  value = merge([for key, values in local.values: { for value in values: value => key}]...)
}
```

**output**

```
Outputs:

vals = {
  "a" = "key1"
  "b" = "key1"
  "c" = "key2"
  "d" = "key2"
}
```

Based on your comment you could essentially convert it to a list of maps where each map has a single map element that you could iterate over

```
locals  {
  values = {
    key1 = ["a", "b"],
    key2 = ["c", "d"]
  }
}

output "vals" {
  value = concat([for key, values in local.values: [for value in values: {(key) = value}]]...)
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Outputs:

vals = [
  {
    "key1" = "a"
  },
  {
    "key1" = "b"
  },
  {
    "key2" = "c"
  },
  {
    "key2" = "d"
  },
]
```

Comment: I'm not trying to make a map out of this, it's more: How do I use it? I need a create some resources which has the same tenancy ID `key`, but different names (`a` and `b`)

Comment: I have added an update that allows a list of maps that map each key to its value